# loadNibNamed does not load the subviews of a XIB file

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I am using `loadNibNamed` to init a custom view. But I see that the subviews are not available when the view is returned.

```
-(instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]){
        NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HRAlternateCategoriesView" owner:self options:nil];

        self = [views firstObject];
        [self setFrame:frame];
    }

    return self;
}
```

viewDidLoad method

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 220);
    self.altCategoryView = [[HRAlternateCategoriesView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [self.view addSubview:self.altCategoryView];
}
```

The XIB file contains 8 subviews (4 buttons and 4 image views) none of which are there in the generated  UIView class. Iam not usng autolayout and size classes.

OS: iOS8

Comment: What calls `initWithFrame:`?  Show us the code.

Comment: Its called inside viewDidLoad method if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Show us the source code of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: done. check it out..

Comment: This does nothing: `self = [views firstObject]`. Why are you using a `UIView` rather than a `UIViewController` to load the nib?

Comment: Why it won't ? In my XIB the class of UIView is my custom class. so it will work.